# Incorrect time display when using time.localtime()

Tags: python, time, pyside6, qmediaplayer

Good afternoon!
I started to develop mp3-player, and faced with incorrect time display when using time.localtime.

I put the current time of playing a song into the current_time variable, and the total duration of the song into the song_duration variable.

```
current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(self.player.position() / 1000))
print(time.localtime(self.player.position() / 1000))
song_duration = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(self.player.duration() / 1000))
print(time.localtime(self.player.duration() / 1000))
self.ui.start_lbl.setText(f"{current_time}")
self.ui.end_lbl.setText(f"{song_duration}")
```

The problem is that the current and remaining time are displayed incorrectly - namely, two extra hours are taken from somewhere (although the song is 4 minutes long).
[image]

I double-checked: time.localtime actually set tm_hour as "2", although the minutes and seconds were calculated correctly (the calculation is based on the player's position).
[image]

Here is the code of the player's own declaration:

```
self.player = QMediaPlayer()
self.audio_output = QAudioOutput()
self.player.setAudioOutput(self.audio_output)
```

I'm new to the topic of working with audio files, so please advise me what needs to be fixed.

I'm trying to understand what exactly was done wrong. The player setup itself is obviously correct: the song plays correctly, and the minutes and seconds in both cases (current time and total time) are shown correctly.

Comment: Why are you labeling the left-hand side of the progress bar with the current time?  Wouldn't you want that to always be 00:00:00 ?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with audio. As the name clearly suggests, `localtime()` converts to the **local time**, you probably live in a time zone that is 2 hours east of UTC. Note that making a function that converts milliseconds to HH:MM:SS is quite simple (it just requires a couple of `divmod()` calls), but in any case, you should either use `gmtime` or, better, the QTime features: `QTime.fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(self.player.position()).toString('HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: @JohnGordon It's common in media player controls to show the current playback time on the left side of the slider (think of Youtube or VLC). Besides, if it always is 00:00:00, it would be quite pointless to show it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @musicamante Oh, it's meant to be the current _elapsed_ time, with an implied starting point of 00:00:00.  I see.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using localtime at all.  If the song has been playing for 30 seconds and it is four minutes long, the display should be `00:00:30 -o---- 00:04:00`, which is completely separate from _my local time_.  Why should it matter that I started playing the song at two o'clock??

Comment: @JohnGordon The OP is using `time` functions to get a formatted `HH:MM:SS` string given a value in seconds; they are not interested in the moment in which playback started, they wanted to use the function implying that the given duration is the start from Epoch, so that they don't need to convert seconds to also get hours and minutes: in that case, a duration in seconds is the same as the seconds past midnight; unfortunately, they used the wrong function, as `localtime` considers the time zone; if they instead did `strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(seconds))` it would probably have been valid.

Answer (score -1):

```
def format_duration(milliseconds):
    # Convert milliseconds to seconds
    total_seconds = int(milliseconds / 1000)
    hours = total_seconds // 3600
    minutes = (total_seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = total_seconds % 60

    # Format time as HH:MM:SS
    return f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}"

# Use the format_duration function to format the current time and song duration
current_time = format_duration(self.player.position())
song_duration = format_duration(self.player.duration())

self.ui.start_lbl.setText(current_time)
self.ui.end_lbl.setText(song_duration)
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to print milliseconds to a readable format, but why their approach has an unexpected result showing a 2 hour difference.